# Web test fails with "404 Not Found" errors when it is run

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013, performance-testing, load-testing

We are doing Performance and Load Testing for Web application which is developed in Angular Java using Visual Studio 2013 ultimate.

Our approach :

1. Record the Web test
2. Play back the web test
3. Do correlate and parameterize etc

The problem now which we are facing is

1. When we record the Login scenario like enter the user name and password in the web test we are not able to find the Form parameters.
2. While running webtest we are getting HTTP Status 404 errors for some files, they are:

   - glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
   - fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
   - glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf

We have tried with the steps below to resolve the above stated errors

1. We checked the Parse Dependents requests for each  request and unparsed the dependents and the respective requests and vice-versa .

however the HTTP status 404 errors for the above files
did not get solved. It is showing same error when we play back our web test.

So can anyone please help us how to resolve this error while running webtest.

Comment: What is meant by the word "bootstrap" in this question?

Comment: You asked a good question, but I think the actual question can be improved to make it more general. Hence I wanted to know why you wrote "bootstrap".

Comment: @Andrian, Ya sure can please edit the question . I used boostrap since development team updated me that they have used bootstrap for the requests so I have added the same in the question. If that is not suitable I would kindly request to suggest me so that I can change accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your web.xml file with the following:

```
<mime-mapping> 
    <extension>woff</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type> 
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping> 
    <extension>eof</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type> 
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping> 
    <extension>ttf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-ttf</mime-type> 
</mime-mapping>
```

Comment: We are using Tomcat 7 server and we removed the above codes from web.xml file and tried still same errors are displayed .Can you please guide us how to resolve

Comment: Sorry I assumed you are using asp.net since you were using VS for web testing. I've updated my answer for Tomcat

Comment: No issues .even i too didnt mention the server details . Now the server is Tomcat 7 and app is build on angular js . Can you please give me some workaround on the issues which am facing.  I have tried with below solution as stated by Andrian the second approach ,it worked fine but its not a correct approach. Your inputs are highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry. I'm not sure what else to try. Can you try loading the app in Chrome and check the network tab and post the errors.

Comment: i  didnt see any errors in network tab , I kindly request to try at your side by recording webtest , URL://http://ec2-54-186-132-2.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/risionWeb/. Can you please try it once Wayne.

Comment: It's working fine from my end. It looks to be a problem with the load test. You may need to exclude it like Adrian suggested below.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to discard the dependant requests before they are issued. You could create plugin to remove these dependant requests. A basic plugin to find and remove requests is below. This can easily be extended to do other comparisons, such as `r.Url.Contains(...)` etc.

```
public class WebTestDependentFilter : WebTestPlugin
{
    public string EndsWithString { get; set; }

    public override void PostRequest(object sender, PostRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        WebTestRequestCollection depsToRemove = new WebTestRequestCollection();

        // Note, you can't modify the collection inside a foreach,
        // hence the above collects requests to remove.

        foreach (WebTestRequest r in e.Request.DependentRequests)
        {
            if ( r.Url.EndsWith(EndsWithString))
            {
                depsToRemove.Add(r);
                e.WebTest.AddCommentToResult(string.Format(
                   "Dependant request ending with \"{0}\" removed : {1}",
                   EndsWithString, r.Url));
            }
        }

        foreach (WebTestRequest r in depsToRemove)
        {
            e.Request.DependentRequests.Remove(r);
        }
    }
}
```

This plugin is based on code described on page 189 of the [Visual Studio Performance Testing Quick Reference Guide (Version 3.6)](http://vsptqrg.codeplex.com/).

Another possibility is to add explicit dependant requests to the web test for these files and set the **Expected HTTP Status Code** property to `404`.

The plugin method is relatively quick and simple. It has the disadvantage that it reduces the load on the servers and the network because the requests are not sent. The second method preserves the requests and so might be considered to be a more realistic performance test.

Whichever route you take, you might report the problem files to your customer as they appear to indicate a fault in the web site.

Comment: @Andrian, I followed the second its working fine but as u stated its an unrealisatic test. So couldnt proceed further. Can you please give some other workaround.

Comment: @PrabhakarY Apologies, typo in original of answer. Setting the expected response code to 404 gives a more realistic test than discarding the responses by plugin. However finding faults in the web site allows you to report them to the developers who can improve performance by removing the request or correct the site by adding the missing files.

Comment: @Andrian, Thanks . I will try once again and keep you updated as my webtest recorder has crashed.I will update you asap..

Comment: @Andrian, Thanks a lot . The second approach worked to my case and now issues are solved